# Can`t boot converted VM from KVM on VMware ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, lvm, gentoo

VM - 3.14.14-gentoo with LVM

Hypervisor - KVM qemu 3.15.7-gentoo

I converted a VM using the command `qemu-img convert -O vmdk`, after that i uploaded the disk to the VMware datastore and created VM with IDE disk.

When i boot (initramfs) i get an error:

> init[1]: segfault at a8 ip 00007f1dde6110ae sp 00007fffe3ddd718 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[7f1dde5e2000+1a2000]
>
> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b

If i boot the system using a gentoo livecd, i can do `modprobe dm-mod` and `vgchange -ay`, after that i can mount my system. So i think LVM is ok.

I do not understand what I need to fix. When i converted VMs without LVM everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `ddb.adapterType` parametr in vmdk file.
First of all we need to convert uploaded disk

> vmkfstools -i /vmfs/volumes/datastore/DiskImage.vmdk -d thin /vmfs/volumes/datastore/DiskImage1.vmdk

After that, open the file with the VI editor and change `ddb.adapterType` from "ide" to "lsilogic".

After that, the VM will start without error.

source: https://nowhere.dk/articles/moving-virtual-machines-from-kvm-to-esxi-6-0